# Rails external URL work as a link in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails app, I have added a string that users can add the link to there facebook profile, it's a simple text field, but in the view I want them to have a link.

For example, if the user adds **www.facebook.com/example** I want it to appear as a link in the views for that I have tried the `link_to` approch but instead of pointing a link to the users profile it just refresh the page.

*This is what I tried*

```
<%= link_to(@user.fblink) %>
```

**migration**

```
class AddFblinkToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :fblink, :string
  end
end
```

**user controller prams**

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:description, :avatar, :location, :fblink, :twlink, :ytlink, :username)
end
```

Comment: Not much to go on here. How is `.fblink` defined?

Comment: i have updated code @lurker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your form is inserted data properly then, You can work on defining a helper class for link like

```
#=> helpers/application_helper.rb
def fb_link(user_fb)
    link_to "Facebook", "#{url_with_protocol(user_fb)}", class: "your-class", target: "new"
end
#=> url helper
def url_with_protocol(url)
    /^http/.match(url) ? url : "http://#{url}"
end
```

Then from view

```
= fb_link(@user.fblink)
```

Or you can work like this

```
= link_to "Facebook", "#{url_with_protocol(@user.fblink)}", class: "your-class", target: "new"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: hey @fool it worked but the problem is it's linking to 
`http://localhost:3000/users/www.facebook.com/example`

Comment: @NoorAliKhan I have updated my answer you can follow this

Comment: it worked...you should change your name dude...you are no fool you are freaking genius...

Comment: @NoorAliKhan it would be better user interface if you will use client side validation for `url` instead of server side as i discussed below.

Answer (score 1):

it will not work as link untill unless its not been saved as `http`,

for example if you want Facebook link to work its should be saved in db as `https://www.facebook.com/example`

so here for this you need a [jquery form validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/url-method/) on your form input field:

and after that in your view page simply you can use it like

> my link <%=@user.@user.fblink%>

do not use `link_to` or any rails view helper here as its complete link is been alredy saved in database.

```
<script>
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      url: true
    }
  }, 
 message: {
   field:{ required: 'fb link can't be blank!', url: 'Please enter valid url'}
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `<%= link_to 'Facebook', @user.fblink %>`

The first parameter of `link_to` method will display the value of the link. In this case it is `Facebook`. The second parameter is the `url_path`. When user click to the `Facebook` link it will go the `url_path`. In this case it is `@user.fblink`.